# Tabulator | Filterbox

Tags: tabulator

Tabulator offers a wide range of options to programmatically filter data, however I could not find a way to render on the page the dropdown and textbox used to actually filter data on the table.
It seems the only option that render a filter element on the Table is: headerFilter.

It looks weird that I have to create dropdown and searchbox myself? 
Here is the link to their page dealing with Filters:  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/filter

Please advise, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of tabulators [Editors](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit#edit-builtin) as [header filters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/filter#header)

The [Examples Page](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1#filter-header) contains a fully working example of a table with a selection of header filters including text boxes and select elements

in the column definition you just have to use the ***headerFilter*** property, in this case we also use the headerFilterParams option to make the select element populate from the names in the column:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name" headerFilter:"select", headerFilterParams:{values:true}}
```

or for a simple input element

```
{title:"Name", field:"name" headerFilter:"input"}
```

Comment: Thank you Oli, I'll give a try, I missed that.

Comment: This works great but how do I reset the filter once selected? Can I add an empty value somehow to the "select" type filter?